# Ethiopic (amharic) font in chromium address bar

Tags: fonts, chromium

The chromium browser does't show amharic letters in the address bar and tabs.

1. It was working with ubuntu 12.04 before. (through ibus-m17n)
2. [Amharic is shown without any issue it Title](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hr8wahu4989gmkb/Selection_002.png?dl=0) bar and it's working well in other applications.
3. Firefox address bar and tabs also [work](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c4zqv58ixep2hya/Selection_003.png?dl=0).

I've tried to change default fonts both in chromioum and system, but nothing's changed.

This is really annoying, I would appreciate any suggestions (apart from "move to firefox")